# How do I access the tag below a header tag(ie <h1>) with bs4/python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have some issues getting into the tag beneath a header tag(h1, h2 etc).

take this page:

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp

lets say I want to get the text in the "definition and usage" header,

```
`<h2>Definition and Usage</h2>`
```

how do I reference the `<p>` block directly below this line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [find_next](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-next-and-find-next) to get the next tag.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
res=requests.get("https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp")
soup=BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html5lib")
h2=soup.find("h2", string="Definition and Usage")
p_after_h2=h2.find_next("p")
p_text_after_h2=p_after_h2.text.replace("\n","")
print(p_after_h2)
print(p_text_after_h2)
```

Output

```
<p>The <code class="w3-codespan">split()</code> method splits a string into a 
list.</p>
The split() method splits a string into a list.
```

The html of the page is

```
...
<div class="w3-example">
  <h3>Example</h3>
  <p>Split a string into a list where each word is a list item:</p>
  <div class="w3-code notranslate pythonHigh">
    txt = &quot;welcome to the jungle&quot;<br><br>x = txt.split()<br><br>
    print(x)</div>
  <a target="_blank" class="w3-btn w3-margin-bottom" href="showpython.asp?filename=demo_ref_string_split">Run example &raquo;</a>
</div>

<hr>

<h2>Definition and Usage</h2>

<p>The <code class="w3-codespan">split()</code> method splits a string into a 
list.</p>
<p>You can specify the separator, default separator is any whitespace.</p>
<div class="w3-panel w3-note">
  <p><strong>Note:</strong> When max is specified, the list will contain the 
  specified number of elements <em>plus one</em>.</p>
</div>

<hr>

<h2>Syntax</h2>

<div class="w3-code w3-border notranslate">
  <div>
    <em>string</em>.split(<em>separator, max</em>)
  </div>
</div>
...
```

This is our response text. Using

```
h2=soup.find("h2", string="Definition and Usage")
```

we get the h2 tag with "Definition and Usage" inside it. Then we find the next p after this h2 tag using

```
p_after_h2=h2.find_next("p")
```

Finally we use

```
p_text_after_h2=p_after_h2.text.replace("\n","")
```

get the text within the `p` tag after removing the newlines.

Answer (score 0):

You could select the whole tag-block its nested in, and then use 2 .split() functions:

```
import lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


CHROME_PATH = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'
CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = 'chromedriver.exe'
WINDOW_SIZE = "1920,1080"

chrome_options = Options()

chrome_options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=%s" % WINDOW_SIZE)

chrome_options.binary_location = CHROME_PATH

url = "Your Url" # Replace with your url
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, chrome_options=chrome_options)
browser.get(url)
innerHTML = browser.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML")
soup = BeautifulSoup(str(innerHTML.encode('utf-8').strip()), 'lxml')

# Identify the enclosing tag that will contain your <h2> tags (before the p)
source = soup.find('name of tag containing h2')
html = str(source).split("</p>")[0]
html = html.split("<h2>Definition and Usage</h2><p>")[1]

# This should give you everything between the tags that you specified.

print(html)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you are able to get to `<h2>Definition and Usage</h2>` with `soup.find_all('h2')[7]`

Now, the element `p` is sibling to above element which can be extracted using `soup.find_all('h2')[7].next_sibling.next_sibling`
This results in

`<p>The <code class="w3-codespan">split()</code> method splits a string into a list.</p>`

Note: we are using 2 `.next_sibling` since first sibling to `<h2>Definition and Usage</h2>` is a newline i.e. `\n`

Checkout more about the usage from official [beautifulsoup doc](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#going-sideways)